# Cohomology with compact support for determinant varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

I wonder if anyone knows anything about the cohomology with compact supports for determinantal varieties, such as the varieties of $m \times n$ matrices of full rank.

Comment: Let $X$ be the space of matrices of full rank. $X$ is a codimension zero submanifold of the vector space of all matrices. By a suitable version of Poincare duality, $H^k_c(X)\cong H_{mn-k}(X)$. Moreover, $X$ is homotopy equivalent to to the Stiefel manifold $V_{m,n}$, whose homology is well-known. Am I missing something?

Comment: And welcome to mathoverflow!

Comment: Welcome to MO, see p.20 http://www.worksing.icmc.usp.br/main_site/2016/JDamon.pdf . It is known theorem of Miller. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03391.pdf . I learned it in his talk in Lille

Comment: Thanks, of course you are right.  Ultimately I am interested in somewhat more complicated problems, in including varieties of rank exactly k, where k < min(m,n).  I guess there the situation is much more complicated, but the cohomology still carries the information.

Comment: Scorza variety, tangents variety, and secants variety like this ? , please edit your question.